# Is pdf() the function underpinning export>save to pdf button in Rstudio?

Tags: r

Is this Rstudio "Save as PDF" button

[image]

internally calling the pdf() function? Thus, would it be equivalent to this chunk of code?:

```r
calibration_simple_plot %>% pdf(file = "plots/ch4/forecasts.pdf",
    width = 6, # The width of the plot in inches
    height = 8) # The height of the plot in inches
dev.off()
```

I would like to automate my saving to PDF process. I am also confused if using Cairo PDF is a better option.

Comment: I don't think so, since `pdf()` **opens** a device - it doesn't open a device and replay the plot (and, it doesn't take a 'file object' as input).  If `calibration_simple_plot` happens to be a `ggplot` you could use `ggsave()` ...